# how to add neo4j cartridge in openshift?

Tags: django, openshift

I am new to openshift and I want to add Neo4j Databse to my django application .I read [this help](https://www.openshift.com/developers/download-cartridges) but I don't know what url must write in `add a cartridge` page in my profile. they say :

> Install your own cartridge:
>   You may also add your own cartridges by providing a link to a downloadable cartridge. OpenShift will download and install the cart into your application. Remember that downloaded cartridges will not automatically receive updates.

I also read [here](http://tomasmuller.com.br/2012/03/29/10-steps-to-run-neo4j-at-redhat-openshift-cloud/) but don't understand what he said .

I must give them https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j url ? or something else ?

Comment: OpenShift currently doesn't have a Neo4j cartridge.  Please [vote for it here](https://www.openshift.com/content/a-neo4j-cartridge).  The second link appears to be a quickstart but it's currently not working for me.  You might want to give it a try and add feedback to the github repo as an issue.